# How to generate a swagger file for the header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in Informatica cloud?

Tags: rest, api, swagger, postman, informatica-cloud

I want to generate a swagger file for rest v2 connector in informatica cloud with these details.

> POST CALL:
>
> Accept: application/json
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> Raw Body:
>      token=XXXXXXX&content=record&format=csv

But informatica cloud does not have an option of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

I am able to do the same request in POSTMAN as POSTMAN has all the functionalities.

I even tried to put the Content-Type separately in the headers section while generating the swagger file in Informatica-cloud, but still didn't work.

Someone told me to use this website: http://specgen.apistudio.io for creating the swagger file, but the site does not seem secure and thus I cannot enter any sensitive data

Is there any way I could generate the file through a website or through informatica itself?

Comment: Is it a requirement to have this file in Informatica Cloud specifically? Or do you simply need the Swagger definition file for this request, e.g. have it locally and use it elsewhere?

Comment: Its not a requirement to have the file in informatica. I though have to specify the path in informatica.
I have also tried https://www.apimatic.io/transformer for creating the swagger. 
I think its the limit of informatica rest connector that does not accept application/x-www-form-urlencoded even if added in the body section.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger file cannot be generated for the header “Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded” in Informatica cloud.

What can be done instead is to use 'Curl' for the rest api call in the pre/post processing command in the Mapping Task/Data Synchronization Task. You can take a look at the curl commands in here:

https://www.baeldung.com/curl-rest

Other way if you want to avoid using Curl then, you can create a 'service connector' for the REST call in the application integration. 
It is also possible to run data integration tasks from application integration if you want to run them after using the service connector.

The way it works is:

1. Create a service connector
2. Create the connection for the service connector
3. Create a process.
4. Inside the process, use various services. First service can run your API connection that you just made, then you can use other service to run a data integration task which is available inside 'System service: -> Run cloud task'.

This way you can make the work done without creating a swagger file as it does not accept “Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded”.